# Error in uploading audio file to server in Android

Tags: android

Please tell me why am I getting this error?

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "rn";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable = 0, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://thinksl.com/taughtable/audiopost.php";
        try
        {
         //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path) );
         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");


         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
         conn.setRequestProperty("userfile",path);
         dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"" +path+ "\"" + lineEnd);
         Log.e("Debug", "Filename: " +path);
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         // close streams
         Log.e("Debug","File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              String str;

              while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
              }
              inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
```

Log cat

> Server Response
>   {"result":0,"post":[],"files":[],"filename":null,"message":"There was
>   an error uploading the file, please try again!"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following method to upload audio file to server.

```
private String uploadAudio(final String filePath) {
        String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
        Log.e(extension);
        String response = null;
        String final_upload_filename = "sample_audio"+ extension;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            URL url = new URL("http://thinksl.com/taughtable/audiopost.php");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", final_upload_filename);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"" + final_upload_filename + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bytessRead;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytessRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                baos.write(bytes, 0, bytessRead);
            }
            byte[] bytesReceived = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            is.close();
            response = new String(bytesReceived);
            Log.e("Server Response" + response);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: what is progressoutputstream

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this,

```
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = "http://thinksl.com/taughtable/audiopost.php";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(path)));
        reqEntity.addPart("filename", final_upload_filename);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + s);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + s);
        status = "" + s;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: {"result":0,"post":[],"files":[],"filename":null,"message":"There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"}

please tell me why the filename is null